# Margin making my page width more than 100%

Tags: html, css, margin

I am having a difficult time locating a `margin` I have coming from the right side of my slide out `nav`.

It appears it is coming from my `nav-panel-container`'s `:after:`, but I do not see anything that would add a `margin` to this.

Does anyone see anything that sticks out that would add this `margin`?

#### Code:

```
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}
.header {
    display: none;
}
.nav-panel from-right {
    display: block;
}
.nav-panel-list {
    display: block;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
.nav-panel-list > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;*/
}
.nav-panel-list > a > li {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #45a5ba;
}
.nav-panel-list > a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.no-touch:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.nav-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 1s;
  transition: visibility 1s;
  z-index: 999999999;
}
.nav-panel::after {
  /* overlay layer */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;
  transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;
}
.nav-panel-header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.96);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s 0s;
  transition: top 0.3s 0s;
}
#nav-slide-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #45a5ba;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
.from-right .nav-panel-header, .from-left .nav-panel-header {
  top: -50px;
}
.from-right .nav-panel-header {
  right: 0;
}
.nav-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-panel-close::before, .nav-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #424f5c;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.no-touch .nav-panel-close:hover::before, .no-touch .nav-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


.nav-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.from-right .nav-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.nav-panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  overflow: auto;
  /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

#### ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: check on every divs... it'll highlight the divs width....

Comment: I did. It was in the nav-panel-container's `:after`, but I don't see anything that would add a margin or extra width to it.

Comment: can you provide the HTML code as well?

Comment: or better, if it's live... can you post the link... it's easy to debug there.

Comment: Sure... Here you are: http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index

Comment: Add a css reset that will probably fix it and any other css bugs that might be browser specific.

Comment: I have a css reset already in my sheet.

Comment: My bad, I assumed that was causing the issue before checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is here

> main-style.css (line 1047):

#### Code

```css
.hand {
  height: auto;
  top: 62%;
  width: 500px;
}
```

this `width:500px` in image is forcing to have 500px no matter what. so you need to have a `max-width` that won't overflow the viewport.

So add `max-width:100%` to it:

#### New Code

```css
.hand {
  height: auto;
  top: 62%;
  width: 500px;
  max-width:100%
}
```

Comment: Are you getting that from my main css or my 640 media query? It doesn't match up to either.

Comment: Seems indeed to be the issue, I recommend google pagespeed insight to quickly detect any elements being outside the viewport and speed issues in the future.

Comment: Hmm weird. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you welcome. if you are building a responsive site, it is always a good practice to set something like this `img { display:block /*fix inline gap*/; max-width:100%; height:auto;}`

Answer (score 1):

add this code... it is on the hand... the image was too big..

```
img.hand {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and a little fix on

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) and (min-width: 640px)
.mobile-header {
   display: block;
   width: 98%; //instead of 100% change it to 98%
   height: 80px;
   margin: 0 2%;
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.hand{ width: 500px; max-width:100%:}
```

Your image width is too big. So give it fix width and also set `max-width` property to in you code. so image get 100% width in your view port. Then also change your media query of your image.